# How to edit messed up version string when updating application in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, version

I'm trying to create an update for an existing iPhone application with iTunes Connect under "Manage Applications."  Unfortunately, I fat-fingered the new version string for the update and cannot correct my mistake.  Does anyone have any insight about 1) fixing the version string, and 2) deleting the update to start over?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Terry,

In iTunes Connect you can reject the binary that you uploaded which removes it from the review queue until you resubmit a new binary.

The version string is stored in the `info.plist` file which should be both in the XCode project and also in the project directory.  This value must match the value you put into iTunes Connect or they will kick back your upload and tell you the two numbers don't match.

Sounds like you just need to reject the binary and correct that version string though.  Hope this helps.

-Rob

P.S.  I've read that if you inserted the wrong version into iTunes Connect instead of the app, you have to contact Apple Support which can take some time.  If it's not too much of a blunder, you might just wanna assume the new version.

Comment: Right.  It's actually the iTunes Connect version string that was fat-fingered.  The version in the binary is correct.  It seems like I cannot edit the iTunes Connect version string for the app.  I'm working with the Apple Support right now.  Hopefully, there will be an easy solution to this.

Comment: Please let us know whatever the outcome.  I don't know why they do it that way... you can't delete old apps either.  They just sort of collect up there as a reminder of your failings :)

Comment: Well, after a few days, here's the response from Apple's iTunes Connect Support.  I don't think we'll get any further progress than this...

Hello,
 
Version numbers cannot be edited once they have been submitted to iTunes Connect.

If you have any further questions regarding this, please let us know.

Best Regards,
iTunes Connect Support 
Apple, Inc. 
1 Infinite Loop 
Cupertino, CA 95014

Comment: Gotta love it... For all of it's brilliance, Apple can be pretty stupid too.